# Turn off corner rounding in matplotlib plot with thicker lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

## Question:

Is it possible to turn off "corner rounding" when using `plot` in matplotlib?

### Setup:

- I am trying to present a complicated nonsmooth function in a presentation.
- As a default (understandably) matplotlib rounds corners. (This is especially visible when the linewidth is increased.)
- I need more linewidth so the plot can be seen when the figure is projected.

### Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1001)
y = abs(x)
plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=10)

plt.show()
```

produces the image:

[image: absolute_value]

### Attempts:

- Increasing the number of points in `x` does not resolve this issue.
- Note that the point `x=0` is included in the plot.

### Summary:

The plotted curve above appears rounded at `x=0` when the function is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify a [`JoinStyle`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_enums_api.html#matplotlib._enums.JoinStyle):

```
plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=10, solid_joinstyle='miter')
```

[image]